# How to see all the warnings in SBT 0.11?

Tags: scala, warnings, sbt

I get notified about "unchecked" warnings when I compile my Scala project with SBT 0.11, but I can't see the warnings themselves.

What I see is

```
[warn] there were 8 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
[warn] one warning found
```

What exactly am I to "re-run with -unchecked" and how to do that? Neither `compile -unchecked`, nor `compile unchecked`, nor `xsbt -unchecked` seem to work.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](http://www.scalafied.com/72/configuring-scala-compile-options-in-sbt-0-10-x-versus-previous-versions).

The solution is to add

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
```

to the project's `build.sbt` file.

It can also take "-feature" as an option and works with sbt 0.13