# How to "re-run with -deprecation for details" in sbt?

Tags: sbt

When I compile Scala code, by running `sbt compile`, [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) says:

```
$ sbt compile
...
[warn] there were 5 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
...
```

How do I do that? (From within SBT?)

Comment: Similar question (that includes the answer to your question) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415962/how-to-see-all-the-warnings-in-sbt-0-11

Answer (score 236, accepted):

### sbt shell

While in sbt shell (if you don't want to change your `build.sbt`):

```
$ sbt
> set ThisBuild/scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
> compile
> exit
```

Due to `in ThisBuild`, `set` applies the settings to all sub-projects, as well.

### Command Line

You could also run the above as a single command on command line.

```
sbt '; set ThisBuild/scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation") ; compile'
```

The trick is to use `;` (semicolons) to separate commands and `'` (ticks) to include all `;`-separated commands as a single argument to sbt.

#### sbt < 1.x

Instead of `ThisBuild/scalacOptions` use `scalacOptions in ThisBuild`

Comment: @retronym: `in Global` instead of `in ThisBuild` also works equally well with subprojects—but why is the latter preferred? or is it even?

Answer (score 30):

```
scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
```

Add this setting to your build.sbt, and, if you have a multi-module project, add it to every project's settings.

Answer (score -3):

As times flows new solutions are emerged. So, now you could re-run the scala compiler without issuing entire project rebuild.

You need to install [ensime-sbt plugin](http://ensime.github.io/build_tools/sbt/):

```
addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime" % "1.0.0")
```

After that you could use the `ensimeCompileOnly` task to compile single file. SBT allows per tasks settings configuration, so you could change for that tasks only:

```
set scalacOptions in (Compile, EnsimeKeys.ensimeCompileOnly) += "-deprecation"
ensimeCompileOnly src/main/scala/MyFile.scala
```

Comment: Adding Ensime just to get `-deprecation` is a terrible idea. Ensime is for supporting on-the-fly annotation in editors. Besides which, Ensime itself has a host of problems with some kinds of projects (most notably those that use macros heavily).

Comment: ensime plugin is a small companion to the fat language server. You could use it separately. Or could just copy some functionality from it.