# sbt 0.12.4 - there were x feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details

Tags: scala, sbt, scalac

I get an error `there were 15 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details` :

```
$ /usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /home/alex/Documents/projects/my_app123/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-android (in build file:/home/alex/Documents/projects/my_app123/)

> compile -feature
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] compile -feature
[error]        ^

> sbt-version
[info] 0.12.4

> compile 
[warn] Credentials file /home/alex/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] Compiling 20 Scala sources to /home/alex/Documents/projects/my_app123/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.12/classes...
[error] there were 15 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 27 s, completed 01 12, 15 1:20:12 PM
```

In **build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
```

I can't find out what that error is because it doesn't say that, even when I run sbt as `$ /usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt -feature`.

```
$ /usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt -feature
[info] Loading project definition from /home/alex/Documents/projects/my_app123/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-android (in build file:/home/alex/Documents/projects/my_app123/)
$
```

It's JDK 1.7

What's the error is and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**:

build.sbt

```
scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
```

or in sbt itself:

`> set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")`

The error remains the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578521/scala-sbt-how-to-re-run-with-deprecation

Comment: @som-snytt, it didn't help.

Comment: You want `-feature`.

Comment: @som-snytt, did you read my question? That's what I did - `-feature`.

Comment: In your update, you added -unchecked and -deprecation, not -feature. If I hadn't read the question, I wouldn't be embroiled in chat just now. But, sorry if the link wasn't useful for you.

Comment: @som-snytt, `$ /usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt -feature`

Comment: There's a perfect answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23927365/56285

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't get a chance to use sbt on a daily basis, so this is just to confirm the suggestion in the linked answer:

```
$ sbt
[info] Set current project to Compiler options (in build file:/home/apm/tmp/sbtwarn/)
> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/apm/tmp/sbtwarn/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[warn] there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Jan 12, 2015 9:45:17 AM
> set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-feature")
[info] Defining {.}/*:scalacOptions
[info] The new value will be used by compile:scalacOptions
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to Compiler options (in build file:/home/apm/tmp/sbtwarn/)
> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/apm/tmp/sbtwarn/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[warn] /home/apm/tmp/sbtwarn/src/main/scala/Sample.scala:6: postfix operator head should be enabled
[warn] by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.
[warn] This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
[warn] or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
[warn] See the Scala docs for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
[warn] why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
[warn]   Console println (List(1,2,3) head)
[warn]                                ^
[warn] one warning found
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 12, 2015 9:45:46 AM
```

Hey, it worked!

Answer (score 9):

You should add

```
scalacOptions += "-feature"
```

to your build.sbt and execute reload if your sbt console is running (or restart it).

Alternatively if you want to set it only for a single session, while in sbt console, you can write `set scalacOptions += "-feature"`, this setting is applied immediately, no need to reload or restart sbt console.

[Re-run with -feature for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926515/re-run-with-feature-for-details)