# Spark - feature warnings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, warnings

I am working through the examples in [Spark in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spark-in-action), and there was an example about implicit conversions in Scala, with code like this:

```
class ClassOne[T](val input: T) { }

class ClassOneStr(val one: ClassOne[String]) {
    def duplicatedString() = one.input + one.input
}
class ClassOneInt(val one: ClassOne[Int]) {
    def duplicatedInt() = one.input.toString + one.input.toString
}
implicit def toStrMethods(one: ClassOne[String]) = new ClassOneStr(one)
implicit def toIntMethods(one: ClassOne[Int]) = new ClassOneInt(one)
```

I input these lines into the spark shell, but after each of the implicit defs I get a warning like this:

```
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
```

It still seems to work, but what does the warning mean?

Comment: Did you re-run? :)

Comment: but not sure what it means, does it mean rerun spark with `spark-shell -feature`?

Comment: scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature") - need to add that to the build def file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-run with -feature for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926515/re-run-with-feature-for-details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add

```
scalacOptions += "-feature"
```

to your `build.sbt` and execute `reload` if your sbt console is running (or restart it).

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895790/sbt-0-12-4-there-were-x-feature-warnings-re-run-with-feature-for-details) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926515/play-re-run-with-feature-for-details).