# Warning:scalac: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details

Tags: intellij-idea

Notice this in the message output:

> Warning:scalac: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details

[image]

What does this mean? And what should I re-run?

I tried rebuilding and syncing the project. But the warning message is still there.

Comment: Your code use some deprecated API or function or something like that. If you add the -deprecation option to the scalac command line you'll get more details

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution from command line:

```
sbt
set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
compile
```

And found the cause of the warning:

```
[warn] Blah.scala:53: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: leaky (Object-receiving) target makes this especially dangerous.
[warn]         signature: Logger.error(x$1: Any): Unit
[warn]   given arguments: <none>
[warn]  after adaptation: Logger.error((): Unit)
[warn]       logger.error()
[warn]                   ^
[warn] one warning found
```

The problem is that I used a deprecated function call `logger.error()`. It is weird that IntelliJ does not give any lint error though.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9578787/1035008