# Running SBT with -deprecation

Tags: scala, sbt

I seem to have warnings in my project/build.scala file (**NOT IN MY SCALA PROJECT**). How do I configure SBT to run with the `-deprecation` flag.

```
// Does not help so do not suggest it!
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
```

I know that SBT has the `sbt.boot.properties` files, but can't figure out if the flag should go in there or not. And if it is an example would be nice. Thx in advance.

BTW

I use SBT launcher for 0.12.2 and have the issue both with SBT 0.12.2 and 0.11.3. And I'm on Ubuntu in case that matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply put the `scalacOptions` setting in `project/build.sbt`. Settings for your project and your build definition go in different files, because they have to be compiled before they can be used and as you want to change compiler settings, this is not possible to handle in the same file.

**edit**: Just to prevent confusion, `./build.sbt`, `project/build.scala` and `project/build.sbt` are different. In the first one you put your normal settings for the project and in the latter two (never both used together) you can put settings that affect the compilation of your project files.

Comment: The downvote was not from me, your answer is actually correct. I guess someone was to quick to judge. Thx again.

Comment: Thx for the edit Randall, but could you explain, how you put settings that affect the compilation of `build.scala` in the file itself?

Comment: Are you maybe confusing `./build.sbt` and `project/build.sbt`?

Comment: +1, but wdym by "never both used together"? `project/build.sbt` and `project/build.scala` seem to play well together.